# Setting QGIS to "show feature count" always when layer is loaded?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3, default-value

I am using QGIS 3.

I know that i can right click the layer and check the "show feature" option but is it possible to show enable this function by default when any layer is loaded ?

I know that we can set the project. I am looking for option to show it all time. a plugin for it will do.

Comment: as a note, including `Show Feature Count`  for each layer in a project can result in extended load times as QGIS has to recount each layer when the project is open.

Answer (score 15):

You can use the following code in the Python Console, script or plugin which sets the `featureCount` setting to be enabled for any loaded vector layer:

```
def showFeatureCount(layers):
    layer = layers[0]
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
        myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)

QgsProject.instance().legendLayersAdded.connect(showFeatureCount)
```

If you want this to work from startup, you can use a [startup script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/318222/qgis-3-startup-script-is-not-executed) (or a plugin) and use the code shown above in addition to importing the following modules:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayer, QgsProject
```

Comment: This should *probably* iterate over all the layers received from the signal, not just the first one.

Answer (score 5):

For any future person reading this thread, there is now an option to show feature count by default when new layer is added.

Go to Settings -> Options -> Canvas & Legend -> tick the box next to *Show feature count for newly added layers*

[image: Settings]