# QGIS 3 startup script is not executed

Tags: qgis-3, error, pyqgis-3

Following the [documentation for QGIS 3 startup script](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#the-startup-py-file), I have placed a `'startup.py'` script in the following path:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\startup.py
```

But the script does not get executed. The script only contains the following line:

```
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Error", "I'm sorry Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that", level=Qgis.Critical)
```

When QGIS loads, it should come up with an error message complaing about `iface` not being recognised. But I receive nothing. I can set up the custom variable and point the path to the Python file but I want to use the startup script method.

Any ideas why?

Comment: $.02: It is philosophically questionable to have an app startup script - supposed to run only once - in a user profile folder. The last profile that was used will be the one loaded next time QGIS starts, and it may or not contain the script. If we run the script when changing profile as well, it could be ran more than once and after the app has started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

QGIS only execute this file if it is put here:

***C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3***

If we see the Core code: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/b53d64bfb0b234cbd5a25fd57d9f07f7309e444c/src/python/qgspythonutilsimpl.cpp#L191

This imports the **startup.py** file and if it is not found here it returns an empty list.

for check it using python:

```
QStandardPaths.locateAll( QStandardPaths.AppDataLocation, "startup.py" )
```

[image]

maybe the documentation is not correct or is a issue in the code

Comment: You're right thanks, I guess the documentation hasn't been updated yet.