# Count features in layers and categories

Tags: pyqgis, rendering, feature-count

I want to automatically count features in my opened layers, and add the result in the layer name, with pyqgis. I can do it with this code :

```
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
   fc = layer.featureCount()
   fc = str(fc)
   layer.setName(layer.name()+" ["+fc+"]")
```

However, it does count features in each *layer*, but not in each *renderer category* when a layer have a categorized style. I was trying something like this just to print the result :

```
for layer in layers:
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    renderert = renderer.type()
    if renderert == "categorizedSymbol":
        for cat in renderer.categories():
            print(cat.label+cat.featureCount())
```

But i get an "*AttributeError: 'QgsRendererCategory' object has no attribute 'featureCount*'"

Do you know how to apply the featureCount() function to layers **and** categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/318223/93097), is this code below a nicer solution ?

I just use the builtin layer function `Show feature count` :

```py
layers = QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
        myLayerNode = root.findLayer(layer.id())
        myLayerNode.setCustomProperty("showFeatureCount", True)
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i needed. It counts the features of layers and categories, and add the result in their name.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter
layer = iface.activeLayer() # My layer 
field_categorized = 'category' # My categorized field 
c = Counter([feature[field_categorized] for feature in layer.getFeatures()]) # Loop on features of the layer 

# Result 
print(c)
Counter({0: 67, 1: 34})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I think it's ok to get one result for one particular category. But J. Monticolo's answer is more simple and add the result to the layer name